# Bash trap exit kill last process

Tags: bash

I have the following in my bash file: (I would like to kill a web server once the bash script is over under any circumstances)

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 12345 &
trap "kill $!" EXIT
```

I am wondering how safe/widespread is this? When will `$!` actually be evaluated (I am pretty sure that this happens at the place of declaration, but still need advice)?

Answer (score 5):

What you wrote is safe. Because you're using double quotes, `$!` is evaluated immediately. If you used single quotes it would be evaluated at the time the script exits.